# How to use jquery mask on a right to left (rtl) field?

Tags: jquery, mask, right-to-left

I want to aply the following mask to a h:inputText - "9.99.999.999999/9999-99"
I managed to do that using the following:

```
rich:jQuery selector="#nuProcesso" query="mask('9.99.999.999999/9999-99',{placeholder:' '})"
```

But I want to use dir="rtl" (right to left) and when I set it in my inputText, the mask gets inverted. So I thought about inverting the mask, but it didn´t work.

Does someone know how to use jquery mask on a rtl field?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

use attr reverse

```
mask('9.99.999.999999/9999-99',{placeholder:' ', reverse: true})
```

Comment: Hello Hugo, thanks for your tip, but it didn´t work. Nothing happened! I tried using with and without dir=rtl. The behavior was the same of when I didn´t use the "reverse: true".

Comment: I am using maskedinput-1.2.2.js

Comment: Using the mask plugin you can try to put a class in your input like this: <input type='text' class='maskCode' />
and in your js code do this:  $(".maskCode").mask("9.99.999.999999/9999-99", { reverse: true});

Comment: Using the method "setMask" of plugin "jquery.meio.mask.js" I managed to pass the parameter "reverse" like following:

rich:jQuery query="setMask({mask: '99-9999/999999.999.99.9', type:'reverse'})"